# Using jQuery to window location to rel value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the jQuery UI-tabs and rather than activate them onclick I am using :hover to change tabs. I would like for the link to take the user to the URL that is specified in the rel attribute, but I'm coming up empty handed in trying to find a solution.

Comment: Can you please write your question in a clearer manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
function hoverEventHandler(){
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("rel");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can bind hover event to the links and select specific tabs based on hovered element:

```
$("a.tab_links").hover(function(){
    var $tabs = $('#example').tabs();

    var selected = $tabs.tabs('select', 2);//select third tab.
});
```

You can use `selected` callback for opening link:

```
$('#example').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var lnk = ui.tab;
        var href = $(lnk).attr("rel");
        OPEN_LINK(href);//write function or code for this
        return false;//don't open on clicking on link;
    }
});
```

PS:- this stuff is from jquery ui tabs [documentation page](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs).